# Workaround for a React-router Route wrapper

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a wrapper for the Route component of React Router, something like this:

```js
import { Navigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function MSRoute({ path, element, isStaff = false }) {
  return (
    <>
      { isStaff
        ? (
          <Route
            path={path}
            element={element}
          />
        ) : (
          <Route
            path="*"
            element={<Navigate to="/" />}
          />
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}

export default MSRoute
```

Basically because I need to restrict some routes for certain types of users, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [MSRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
```

Is there any way of doing this? Any clean workaround?

regards

Comment: What needs to use the `isStaff` prop value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Uncaught Error: [MSRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>` is informing you that `Route` components can only be rendered by a `Routes` or other `Route` component. `MSRoute` is neither a `Route` nor `React.Fragment`, so it can't be rendered as a child of the `Routes` component.

It seems you are wanting to either render the routed component or redirect based upon the `isStaff` prop value. In order for `MSRoute` to be a wrapper component it needs to wrap and render the `children` prop.

Example:

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'

function MSRoute({ children, isStaff = false }) {
  return isStaff ? children : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
}
```

Usage:

```
<Route
  path={path}
  element={(
    <MSRoute isStaff={isStaff}>
      {element}
    </MSRoute>
  )}
/>
```

If you have the need to wrap several routes with this `isStaff` check then you can convert `MSRoute` into a layout component that renders an `Outlet` for nested routes instead of rendering a single child component.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

function MSRoute({ isStaff = false }) {
  return isStaff ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
}
```

Usage:

```
<Route element={<MSRoute isStaff={isStaff} />}>
  <Route path={path} element={element} />
  ... other routes
</Route>
```